# Is it possible to change image position and width with php GD?

Tags: php, image, gd

I have a gif file with many icons and buttons on it..
What I want to do is include that gif file using php gd `somefunction("file.gif")`

then, resize the new image to 30px by 30px.. and then be able to position (using x and y coordinates) the actual gif file, so that only a certain area of the image shows on the new file..

just like the css background-position property but, with gd.
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

imagecopyresized() resizes the image, so it doesn't quite work for what I was exactly looking for.

For anyone else that might need this, the best function is actually imagecopy().
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php

It will do the trick.. 
Thanx Trufa for the quick answer though.

Answer (score 0):

imagecopyresized()

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

Should do the trick for adjusting the size.

Comment: What do you mean "a gif file with many icons and buttons on it"?

Comment: Thanx for that bro. Actually I tried that function and it wasn't quite what I was looking for, so I looked through the gd section on php.net and imagecopy() was able to do the trick

Comment: Great, and the position part did you get it or do you need some help?